# How to change backgroundColor of selected Tab in react-native-tab-view

Tags: react-native, react-native-tab-view

I use react-native-tab-view. So how to set background color only to selected tab?
This is what I have...

```js
<TabView
                navigationState={this.state}
                renderScene={SceneMap({
                  first: FirstRoute,
                  second: SecondRoute,
                  third: ThirdRoute,
                  fourth: FourthRoute,
                })}
                onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
                initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height }}
                useNativeDriver = {true}
                renderTabBar={(props) =>
                    <TabBar
                      {...props}
                      indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                      style={{backgroundColor: "black", height: 40}}
                      renderIcon={this.renderIcon}
                      indicatorStyle={{backgroundColor: "#555555"}}
                    />
                  }
                />
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

This works for text style change. The only difference in your case is that instead of changing the styles on the "Text" tag inside `renderlabel` you'd have to change the styles of the "View" tag.

```
renderLabel={({ route }) => {
  return (
    <View> //THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT THE CONDITIONAL STYLING
      <Text
        style={
          route.key === props.navigationState.routes[this.state.index].key
            ? styles.selectedTabTextStyle
            : styles.label
        }
      >
        {route.title}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}}
```